# modify loop to exclude posts which belong to a certain category AND no other categories

Tags: wordpress

In Wordpress:

I have a need to exclude a certain category of posts from the main WP loop. But only if that post has no other categories.

For example, if the category in question was called `X`...

Test 1: A post which belongs to only `X` category would be excluded.

Test 2: A post which belongs to `X` and `Y` categories would be included.

Test 3: Posts which belong to `Z` or `Foo` or anything else would also be included.

I have the following code so far:

```
function exclude_category( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    $query->set( 'cat', '-271' );
    }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category' );
```

But this works for test 1 and 3 (above) but not test 2. How can I modify the query to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I thought up a way to do this, though I am not sure it is the *best* way.

Basically I am asking WP for a list of all categories then I am concatenating a list of those categories minus the one which I want to exclude. I then feed that into the 'cat' parameter in the WP Query. It seems to work as I would hope, but it also seems a little round-about. I would appreciate any feedback.

In this case `271` is the id for my `x` category.

```
function exclude_category( $query ) {

    $terms = get_terms( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'hide_empty' => false,
    ) );

    $catquery = "";
    foreach($terms as $term) {
        if($term->term_id != 271) {
            $catquery .= $term->term_id . ",";
        }
    }

    $catquery = substr($catquery, 0, -1);

    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
         $query->set( 'cat',  $catquery  );
    }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category' );
```

**EDIT**

I ended up changing it to a taxonomy query so I could set `include_children` to false.

```
function exclude_category( $query ) {

    $terms = get_terms( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'hide_empty' => false,
    ) );

    $catarray = [];
    foreach($terms as $term) {
        if($term->term_id != 271) {
            array_push($catarray, $term->term_id);
        }
    }

    if ( $query->is_main_query() &&  $query->is_home()) {
         $query->set( 'tax_query', array(  array(
             'taxonomy' => 'category',
             'field' => 'term_id',
             'terms' => $catarray,
             'include_children' => false
            )));
    }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category' );
```

Answer (score -1):

I would assume that including all category y, will include all posts contained in x and also in y.

Comment: you gave a case scenario, i gave the solution to eliminate all posts in category x, because you don't understand, doesn't mean its incorrect, guess you were expecting me to write your code for you